# How to change image height with one provided by the user (prompt)

Tags: javascript

Second part of the code (starting with var newHeight) does not work - what is wrong?

```
  /* var getDim = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var a = getDim[0].height;
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  target.innerHTML = "<p>This image has" + " " + a + " " + "pixels.</p>"; */

  var newHeight = prompt("Provide new height"); // 2nd part
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var theOne = image[0];
  if (isNaN(newHeight) === false) {
    theOne.style.height === newHeight;
  }
  else {
    alert("Provide a proper value!")
  }
```

Comment: could you define what `does not work`? Where does the second part start? Maybe provide a fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I'll improve me future questions quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line:

```
theOne.style.height = newHeight;
```

instead

```
theOne.style.height === newHeight;
```

The second one is an expression, not an assignment.